# Keyboard Events/shortcuts in UIList?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, shortcut

I noticed that when the cursor is hovering a UIList and you press the keyboard arrows, it changes the index:

[image]

I was wondering if we are able to modify or extend that behaviour. So, for example, if we press `CTRL+UpArrow`, we could call an operator or make something else?

I didn't found any clue in the API, so I just wanted to ask in case some more experienced user have any info, in case this is possible (if so, how?)

Thank you so much for the help or any info!